# a:hover style does not affect after adding cufon

Tags: html, css, hover, cufon

I have the following code that worked perfectly before adding cufon in the HTML:

```
<div id="pageNumbers" class="fl">
<ul>
<li id="selected"><a href="">1</a></li>
<li><a href="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="">3</a></li>
<li><a href="">4</a></li>
<li><a href="">5</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end pageNumbers -->


#pageNumbers a:hover
{
  color:#FFF;
  height:26px;
  width:27px;
  padding: 5px 12px 5px 11px;
}
```

But after adding cufon in the in the HTML it doesn't work. The question is how can I make cufon understand and apply my style?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `Cufon.replace('#pageNumbers a', {hover: true});`?

Comment: No problem, I will add it as answer. Please don't forget to accept so others know it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cufon API](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API), `hover` is turned off by default to improve performance. So you need to turn `hover` on for any elements that need to be drawn differently on hover.

This can be done using the following code:

```
Cufon.replace('#pageNumbers a', {
    hover: true
});
```